# Extending highlight on line number to ALE gutter as well

Tags: vim, vimrc

I have `set cursorline` enabled, and [it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSfk7.png). I'm also using [ALE](https://github.com/w0rp/ale) to lint my code, and I have the sign gutter set to show always (`g:ale_sign_column_always`). However, in filetypes that ALE knows how to lint, the row in the gutter [is not highlighted with the rest of the line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIESl.png). Is there any way to make this happen? I'd like the darker gray line to extend to the edge of the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's just [`:help hl-CursorLineNr`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#hl-CursorLineNr) for the number column, but no corresponding highlight group for the sign column. At that is on the far left, and highlighting there could interfere with the sign highlighting itself, it probably was not deemed worthy to implement.

Comment: Ah dang, thought something like that might've been the case. Thanks anyway!